# How to model beam on elastic foundation in ABAQUS

Tags: finite-element-analysis

I am trying to model a simple 2D beam on elastic foundation in Abaqus. How to do this in ABAQUS? Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Model the beam as simple 2D QUAD elements.
2. See if ABAQUS has any infinite elements to model the foundation.  If not, you'll have to discretize a large body that exhibits the "foundation" behavior (e.g. asymptotic Laplace like behavior far away from the surface).
3. Depending on the physics you want to capture, you'll have contact and friction defined along the contact surface between the foundation and the beam.  These will make your problem non-linear and harder to solve, but may be more faithful to the physics you're trying to model.  It'll allow gaps between the beam and the foundation.

I'm so glad to see so many ABAQUS questions here.  No MSC, MARC, Ansys?  From this perspective, HKS has 100% market share.

Comment: I am doing 2D analysis means modeling beam as a line. I am not going for quad elements. 2D, I mean, is X, Y, XY rotations. Beam will be a line.

Comment: B21 2-node linear beam or quadratic B22 I am using here. I guess I should have provided more info. in problem description. For such linear beam, how to connect a spring at one end and other end to ground? Abaqus has spring connection between 2 point option available. But I am not getting how to connect spring to ground.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ground".  If a spring has two nodes, and you connect one to the beam, then by default you must set the boundary condition for displacements on the other end to be (0,0).  Is that how you're representing the foundation?  Springs?  How are you calculating the stiffness of the spring?

Comment: By ground, I mean displacement and rotation at that end should be zero. So should I just create a datum point there fix it for dof's? You are right, one end of spring will connect beam, other end will have all dof (X,Y,rotation in XY) zero. I have stiffness of spring.